# slam_karto marks grid cell underneath real robot as occupied

Tags: ros, exploration, laserscan, hector-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here are 3000 words :P

When `slam_karto` starts (on a real robot, not simulation), it marks a few cells underneath the robot as occupied. In the screenshot below, the red arrow corresponds to the robot's initial pose, i.e. `[0 0 0]`

[image: image description]

In turn, this causes planning to fail, since the robot is in the "lethal cost" region of the global costmap. (I'm actually doing exploration here, using the `hector_navigation` package, not navigation.)

[image: image description]

Looking at the incoming `LaserScan` messages, there don't seem to be any measurements at such short range (see screenshot below, where the decay time has been set to 30 sec.) The messages' `range_min` field is `0.06`. I'm building the LiDAR driver from source, so I tried increasing that, e.g. to `0.15`. But it didn't have any effect on the issue at hand. For reference / comparison, this map's resolution is `0.05`

[image: image description]

This problem doesn't arise in simulation though. I can't seem to find any relevant parameters I could tune in order to prevent this. How should I go about debugging it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232523/slam_karto-marks-grid-cell-underneath-real-robot-as-occupied/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the following function in `Karto.h`

```
inline const PointVectorDouble& GetPointReadings(kt_bool wantFiltered = false) const
```

is NEVER called with `wantFiltered = true` And there is no parameter for adjusting this. Thus, Karto's mapper uses measurements whose range is smaller than the LiDAR's `min_range`. I think these don't show up in RViz exactly because they are below `min_range`; RViz probably filters them out.

Edit: I opened a pull request: https://github.com/ros-perception/open_karto/pull/9

PS. The reason this doesn't occur in simulation is because the simulated LiDAR measurements are always between `min_range` and `max_range`

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1